# How to get properly formatted JSON array from SQL query that uses FOR JSON PATH?

Tags: php, json, t-sql, pdo

I am using a sql query with FOR JSON PATH that should give a JSON result. However, I'm not sure how to return the result in PHP. The command works perfectly as a SQL command but when executing it as a prepared statement I encounter some issues.

This is my query...

```
$getUsersTeams = $this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT T.Id AS Id, T.TeamName AS TeamName, T.TeamImage AS Image, T.Description AS Description, T.IsActive AS IsActive, TU.IsAdmin AS IsAdmin,
                                                    ( SELECT TU.UserId AS id, U.FirstName, U.LastName, U.DisplayPicture
                                                    FROM TeamUsers TU
                                                    INNER JOIN Users U ON TU.UserId = U.Id
                                                    WHERE TU.TeamId = T.Id
                                                    FOR JSON PATH
                                                    ) AS [Members]
                                                    FROM TeamUsers TU
                                                    INNER JOIN Teams T ON T.Id = TU.TeamId
                                                    WHERE UserId = :userId
                                                    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, ROOT('Teams')");
            $getUsersTeams->bindParam(':userId', $this->userId);

            if(!$getUsersTeams->execute())
            {
                return false;
            }

            $usersTeamsResult = $getUsersTeams->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        header("content-type: application/json");
        echo $usersTeamsResult;
            exit;
```

I've tried doing fetch, fetchall and also a while loop to get the data.

From all 3 of those methods i've tried, it always just echoes "Array". Though, 
if I do this with fetchAll...

```
echo json_encode($usersTeamsResult);
```

...then the result at least echoes, but in an incorrect format, like so...

```
"JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B": "{\"Teams\":[{\"Id
\":1,\"TeamName\":\"GroupName1\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,
\"IsActive\":true,\"IsAdmin\":false,\"Members\": .....ETC   "}]}]}"
```

I didn't include the whole response, but this is the jist of it. 
I've tried stripslashes to remove the slashes but that doesn't work.

I just want to get the response and echo that as it is. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to delete this line `header("content-type: application/json");` and keep this one  `$array = son_encode($usersTeamsResult);`

Comment: This is common when a string is double encoded in json. make sure you encode it only once

Comment: I tried     
    $usersTeamsResult = $getUsersTeams->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($userTeamsResult);
    exit; But I just get null, tried with fetchAll too...

Comment: did you try to decode the json once to see if you have a valide json string again? Don't json_encode($userTeamsResult), $userTeamsResult is already encoded

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it gives me null, the only thing that returns any data is using fetchAll, json_encode and the header application/json

Comment: I got json_decode to work, but only if it is like this 

$usersTeamsResult = $getUsersTeams->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $usersTeams = json_decode($usersTeamsResult, true);

Comment: When you get a response that says "Array" it's because you can't echo an array. try print_r($usersTeamsResult) instead to see the actual array also, if json_decode works, that means it's somehow already encoded lol

Comment: I've tried that and a I get a response like this, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with this. I just want to get this back as JSON

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B] => {"Teams":[{"Id":1,"TeamName":"Group 1 Name","Image":null,"Description":null,"IsActive":true,"IsAdmin":false,"Members":[{"id":1, .... ETC ... "}]}]}
        )

)`

Comment: I would assume it's something happening with fetchAll when using FOR JSON PATH. It's like fetchAll is converting it to an array with the content of the array being the JSON of the query. I think I need to somehow take the JSON out of that array and decode that instead, though I could be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by doing this, not sure why I have to go through all this to get it working, but yeah...

```
$usersTeamsResult = $getUsersTeams->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $myArray = $usersTeamsResult[0];
            $usersTeams = json_decode(array_shift($myArray), true);
```

Then $usersTeams is the properly formatted associative array which I can then encode with json_encode.